# Customize lines in ggplot linegraph with multiple lines

Tags: r, ggplot2, linegraph

I build this graph:

```
labels.minor <- c("nie","selten","manchmal", "mehrmals", "oft", "sehr oft", "immerzu")

df_ebf <- df_ebf %>%
  map_df(rev)


ggplot(data=df_ebf, aes(x=forcats::fct_inorder(Skalen), y=Werte, group="")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Werte, color = "#003560")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = SD_plus, color = "#8DAE10", linetype = "dashed")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = SD_minus, color = "#8DAE10",linetype = "dashed")) +
  geom_point(color = "#003560") +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(x="EBF-Skalen") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 6), breaks = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6), labels = paste0(0:6, "\n", labels.minor), sec.axis = sec_axis(~.x, breaks = 0:6)) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) +
  theme(panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),axis.line.x = element_line(size = 1, colour = "black", linetype=1),axis.title=element_blank())
```

[image]

But instead of changing the style of the lines, the styling just appears in the legend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take them out of the aes:

aes(...), color="..", linetype=".."

Comment: at this point, you might be better of reshaping the data using pivot_longer , this will let you gruop the lines by which set they are in, and define using aesthaetics what shapes and colors you should have, and have them represented properly in the legend. But this might be beyond the scope of this question at this level